# Expanding two iterated limits into quantifiers?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, logic, first-order-logic

I have always had a little trouble fully understanding iterated limits. So I thought it might be a good exercise to expand it in quantifiers.

Suppose we want to expand $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} f'(x) = L$. So we want to expand

$$\lim_{x \to a} \left( \lim_{h \to x} \dfrac {f(h) - f(x)}{h-x} \right) = L$$

So first expanding the outer limit (I'm not even sure how to expand the inner limit first) we have

$$\forall (\epsilon > 0) \exists (\delta > 0) \forall(x \in \mathbb{R}): |x-a| < \delta \implies \left|  \lim_{h \to x} \dfrac {f(h) - f(x)}{h-x} -L  \right| < \epsilon $$

However, I'm not really sure how to expand this further.

Any help in this regard, or in understanding iterated limits better, is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Oh thanks for enlightening me on that distinction. If it had been an iterated limit instead, would there be a way to expand it further than I did this one?

Comment: Eh, there was some imprecision in my comment, and I don't have time to fix it now, so I've deleted it. I'll respond later if someone else hasn't.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Alright thanks

Comment: @symplectomorphic Sadly no one has answered yet. If you have time, would you mind posting a reply?